# Cross validation in CATBOOST Regressor: ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, catboost

I have a dataframe  which has **no null values, and has only numerical** **values** (I have done necessary transformations)

CATBOOST implementation

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
CatBoost_clf=CatBoostRegressor()
CatBoost_clf.fit(X, y)
print('Train Accuracy',cross_val_score(CatBoost_clf, X_train, y_train, 
    cv=3, scoring='accuracy'))
print('Test Accuracy',cross_val_score(CatBoost_clf, X_test, y_test, cv=3, 
    scoring='accuracy'))
```

Error

```
> ----> 5 print('Accuracy:',cross_val_score(CatBoost_clf, X, y, cv=3, scoring='accuracy'))

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets
```

How to calculate cross validation accuracy (cv=3 or 3 iterations of validation sets) on CATBOOST?( output y has values 0 and 1 )

Comment: The message is clear. You can't run accuracy on regression predictions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should use is `CatBoostClassifier`.

You are using `CatBoostRegressor`, which is designed to minimize the error based on continuous values (e.g., 0.43823). A classifier, for instance `CatBoostClassifier`, takes categorical input values(e.g., 0 or 1), which is what you have. In your example, the `y` is:

```
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
```

Which is definitely categorical, and not continuous.